# How do I connect a Python and a Processing script

Tags: python, c, processing

I want a Python script and a Processing script (written in C) to exchange data. How do I build a communication between them?

I want to use this exchange of data like a serial communication. The goal is to simulate a robot controlled by a Raspberry graphically in Processing.

Comment: some sort of file?......

Comment: Check out this article about the different approaches that exist for inter-process communication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication. If you don't have control over the processing script, a file or pipe might be your best option.

Comment: If you don't want to use files and want direct communication, you can use UDP to communicate on a given port.

Comment: I want to use this exchange of data like a serial communication. The goal is to simulate a robot controlled by a Raspberry graphically in Processing.

Comment: @Nofix, can you give me more information on your idea?

Comment: @Schnopop Let me write a short answer with an example.

Comment: How do you write a `Processing` script in C? To the best of my knowledge, C isn't a language to which Processing has been ported. I suspect that you are using the tag `processing` generically rather than for its intended purpose (a specific graphics language which is based on Java).

Comment: @JohnColeman Well, this is my fault, I always thought Processing comes with C because the Arduino IDE does so. Sorry!

Comment: @Schnopop Processing does have a well-developed [Python mode](http://py.processing.org/). It might be easiest to use that directly. Then you wouldn't have to worry about interfacing two languages.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess you could use UDP datagrams to communicate between C and Python.

## If you have to send from Python to C

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
YOUR_DATAS = "Some datas"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "datas to send:", YOUR_DATAS

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(YOUR_DATAS, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

(taken from https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) 
I guess you'll need to add a While loop to this example to send your datas.

Then create an `UDP` client in `C` that receives the data from you `python` script.